# Firing a segue from a different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, segue

I have a segue that navigates from FirstViewController to SecondViewController. This happens by the press of a button. The code for the button is

```
- (IBAction)segue:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

This happens correctly when i press the button.

What i am trying to do is fire this method from another view. I tried doing

```
FirstViewController fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[fvc segue:nil];
```

When i try this, I get the error message, Reciever  has no segue with identifier 'myIdentifier'

How do i fire this segue programatically from another view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here, but they boil down to a couple of key points:

- Segues are a storyboard thing, so view controllers only "know" about segues if they're instantiated from a storyboard.
- A view controller must be onscreen to perform a segue.
- Segues are transitions from one specific view controller to another specific view controller.

So, in your snippet:

```
FirstViewController fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[fvc segue:nil];
```

The first problem is that `alloc`-`init`-ing gives you an instance of `FirstViewController` that doesn't know anything about the storyboard it came from, so it doesn't know anything about segues. (This alone could be fixed using [`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`][1], but that doesn't solve your whole problem.) A second problem is that this instance doesn't fit anywhere into the UI hierarchy -- it hasn't been presented as a modal view controller, it's not the top view controller in the current navigation controller, it's not the visible window's root view controller, etc. In order to transition the screen from one view to another, the first view needs to be onscreen.

What it sounds like you want to do is transition from what's currently onscreen to the target of this segue. But the notion of a storyboard segue isn't just a transition with a destination -- it's a source, a destination, and a transition or relationship between them. If you have a different source view, you need a different segue. So, if you already have a segue from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`, and you want to make a similar transition from `OtherViewController` (assuming that's the one onscreen now) to `SecondViewController`, you need to make a second segue connecting `OtherViewController` to `SecondViewController`.

Comment: Nice explanation. @rickster , it there a way to fire a segue without the press of a button ?

Comment: You can put `[someVC performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" sender:whatever]` pretty much anywhere -- all it requires is that `someVC` be the currently visible view controller (and that it was instantiated via storyboard).